# Casting a reference to a base class: standard behaviour?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, reference

I have a situation like the following:

```
class Getter
 {public: virtual void doSomething {std::cout<<"Nothing";};
  };
class Getter_A: public Getter
 {public: void doSomething {std::cout<<"A";};
  };
class Getter_B: public Getter
 {public: void doSomething {std::cout<<"B";};
  };
```

I then have a block of code in which I want to use one of those Getter things. Thus, in English, I would have this:

```
{Getter & getter=wantA?Getter_A():Getter_B;
 getter.doSomething();
 };
```

Of course in C++ this won't quite work because the ternary operator isn't quite clever enough to look for a common base class, so I do this:

```
{Getter & getter=wantA?(Getter &)Getter_A():(Getter &)Getter_B;
 getter.doSomething();
 };
```

This is elegant and readable. The question is whether it works in C++. Since there are no C++ compilers, and since I cannot find a definitive answer in a reference book, I am asking here.

**Common ground:** The "compilers of a language resembling C++" I have tried do the following:

1. Create either a `Getter_A` or a `Getter_B` object.
2. Make a call to `doSomething`.
3. Delete the created object.

The open question is: *which doSomething to call?*

Clang on the Mac calls `Getter_A::doSomething()` or `Getter_B::doSomething()`. Thus, behind the scenes, that `Getter&` reference is a reference to either a `Getter_A` object or a `Getter_B` object.

Visual C++ 6.0 calls `Getter::doSomething()`. Thus, behind the scenes, it strips the `Getter_A`ness from the created object and makes a reference to a naked `Getter` object instead. This becomes more spectacular if `Getter::doSomething` is made pure rather than having a body.

Now, Visual C++ 6.0 is famous for not compiling C++ but a completely different language with the same name. Nevertheless, it would be good to know whether *C++ itself* (as opposed to this or that compiler writer's idea of what C++ is) expects a base-class reference to continue to be a reference to the original object in all its glorious virtuality, or whether Microsoft are, in this case, correct to strip the object naked when casting its reference.

The work-round I have come up with, and tested, is:

```
{Getter_A a; Getter_B b;
 Getter &getter=*(wantA?(Getter *)&a:&b);
 getter.doSomething();
 }
```

which, since compilers respect the privacy of pointers, seems to be safe everywhere. But this is a messy bit of language and it would be good to know what a real, standards-conforming C++ compiler would do about casting references to a base class.

Comment: Asserting "there is no C++ compilers" on [tag:c++] is bound to trigger a handful of existential crises ;)

Comment: Can you explain what "there are no C++ compilers" means? Especially given gcc, Visual Studio, clang, https://godbolt.org/ and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ ?

Comment: Re: "3. Delete the created object." -- certainly not. **Destroy** the created object. Compilers never generate code that deletes an object. That's a user-level decision.

Comment: The "work-round" is the way to do it in C++.  As a pointer `Getter* getter` would be slightly more idiomatic C++, imo.  But the reference is reasonable too.  Alternatively, `std::unique_ptr<Getter>`, if having a heap allocation is acceptable.  `Getter&` won't extend the lifespan of a temporary, you'd need `Getter const&` to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your "elegant and readable" approach has a typo, and you intend it to read

> ```
> {Getter & getter=wantA?(Getter &)Getter_A():(Getter &)Getter_B();
> getter.doSomething();
> };
> ```

(note the `()` after `Getter_B` which are missing in your description).

In any event, this gives undefined behaviour since the object chosen ceases to exist before the statement `getter.doSomething()`.   So testing which `doSomething()` is called is academic - even if two compilers give different results, they are both correct.

What you need to do is ensure the object you use continues to exist until the call.

There are various ways, such as (essentially) your "workaround".

```
 Getter_A a;
 Getter_B b;

 Getter &getter = wantA ? (Getter &) a : (Getter &) b;
 getter.doSomething();
```

or  (more explicitly)

```
 Getter_A a;
 Getter_B b

 Getter &ra(a), &rb(b);
 Getter &getter = wantA ? ra : rb;
 getter.doSomething();
```